# If one column values are null order by to another columns values in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am showing user details in a table list order by updated date and time. If the updated date and time is null have to order by created date and time. [image: Please check the image, how to show the list]

Comment: Pls share your code

Comment: User::orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(updated_at), created_at'), 'ASC')->get();
I wrote above code in controller  for getting user details and show in table list @Sehdev

Comment: try this:
->select(['*', DB::raw('IF(`updated_at` IS NOT NULL, `updated_at`, `created_at`) `sortOrder`')])
        ->orderBy('sortOrder', 'asc');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use IF condition in your query to resolve this issue:

```
->select(['*', DB::raw('IF(`updated_at` IS NOT NULL, `updated_at`, `created_at`) `sortOrder`')])
->orderBy('sortOrder', 'asc');
```